# How to make the @apply tailwind directive to work in Django?

Tags: django, tailwind-css

do u know how to make the @apply tailwind directive to work in django static css files?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3vvn.jpg)

My css static files are working perfectly, but the @apply directive not.

I followed the official docs to set tailwind and django:
[Django + Tailwind](https://django-tailwind.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well i have to answer to my own question.
The way to fix this is to use the styles.css file inside the "theme/static_src/src" folder created by the django_tailwind package, see the following image as reference:

[tailwind + django css file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7a7m.png)

This is the only file that works with tailwind directives like @apply.